# Replace a string only if the next line has another specific string

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to replace a string on a line, only if the next line has a specific string.

I have:

```
13963   12602   gene
13963   12602   rRNA
```

And the result need be

```
13963   12602   rRNA
13963   12602   rRNA
```

Where the numbers vary...
So I tried:

```
VAR_1=$1

if [grep rRNA -B1  $1 |awk '{print $3}' |head -n1 ='gene']
 then
   sed 's/gene/rRNA'
fi
```

And I get

```
line 5: [grep: command not found
head: =gene]: No such file or directory
```

And I don't quite know where to go from here...

Comment: so everything is hardcoded? if the next line is `rRNA` and this line has `gene` then change the `gene` into `rRNA`?

Comment: yep. That is it.

Comment: If simply **always** printing `rRNA` as the 3rd field isn't all you need then [edit] your question to provide more truly representative sample input and expected output that includes cases where the 3rd output fields must not be `rRNA`. Right now `awk '{$3="rRNA"}1' file` would produce your expected output from your sample input so if that's not all that's needed then that's not a good example.

Comment: Must `gene`, or `rRNA`, or **both**, have to be **complete** words, or can they be substrings in longer words? For example `eugene` or `generic` - does that count as `gene`? Also - assuming you really mean "complete words" -  are they always at the end of the line, or can they appear anywhere? Can `gene` appear more than once, and if so, do you need to replace ALL occurrences on that line? Can `gene` and `rRNA` appear on the SAME line, and if they can, what is the desired handling?

Comment: ... and, by the way - do the numbers need to match on the two lines? Or is that a pure coincidence in your sample?

Comment: @mathguy. Both are complete and exact words. They are always at the end of the line, but I only want to find the one on the line immediately before the line that has rRNA. They are never in the same line and the numbers are the same for both lines.

Comment: That is what I assumed in my solution.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($NF=="rRNA"){
    a[FNR]=$NF
  }
  next
}
((FNR+1) in a){
  $NF=a[FNR+1]
}
1
'  Input_file  Input_file | column -t
```

OR in case you want to have a variable in `awk` where you could define string to be looked in Input_file then try following.

```
awk -v str="rRNA" '
FNR==NR{
  if($NF==str){
    a[FNR]=$NF
  }
  next
}
((FNR+1) in a){
  $NF=a[FNR+1]
}
1
'  Input_file  Input_file | column -t
```

**Logical explanation:**

- Reading Input_file 2 times here.
- When Input_file is being read first time then its looking for those lines which have string rRNA in its last field.
- Then it's creating an array whose index is that line number and value is last field of that line.
- next will skip all further statements
- Now checking condition `(FNR+1) in a` which will be checked when Input_file will be read 2nd time. It's checking if current line's line number + 1 is present in array or not.
- if it's coming in array then set array value to last field of current line
- 1 will print lines.

Comment: @SilviaJusti, added detailed level explanation too now kindly do lemme know in case of any queries here.

Comment: Reading the input file twice? Not too efficient, is it?

Comment: @mathguy, hi, yeah I could create an array and would have done too but for simplicity purposes i did that. But storing whole file into an array and at last playing with it in end block cold have been memory taking too IMHO. Since OP haven't mentioned about size so I choose simple logic one :)

Comment: The problem admits at least one solution (and I believe many more, including using `awk`) where editing is done while streaming the data from the file just once. I showed one such approach in my solution, using `sed`. In this problem it is entirely possible that the file is small, so it wouldn't matter - but it may also be very big.

Answer (score 0):

Let `sed` consider newlines as plain characters, this is option `-z`.
When `gene` is followed by a newline, and on the next line (substring until next newline) the string `rRNA` is at the end of the line, replace `gene`.

```
sed -rz 's/gene\n([^\n]*)(rRNA\n)/\2\1\2/g' "$1"
```

Comment: This will pretty much negate stream processing, won't it? The entire input file needs to be read and processed as a single "line".

Comment: @mathguy OP uses `$1` as inputfile in his code attempt, so I ignored the streaming problem and hope that the file is limited in size.

Comment: What's that got to do with streaming? Using $1 simply means the OP wants to pass in the filename as an input, rather than hardcoding it as I did; why would that by itself negate stream processing?

Comment: With streaming I think of piping the output of some other process, `longlastingprocess | showresultsastheycome`. The first process can be finished after hours. This streaming situation would be even more difficult for the  `awk ... Input_file Input_file` solution. You are right that streaming also applies to files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `sed` solution, with the following assumptions: you are looking for consecutive rows where the fixed words `gene` and `rRNA` (as complete words, not word fragments) appear at the end of the first, resp. second line, and in those cases, replace `gene` with `rRNA`. The numbers preceding these words play no role. (If instead they must be matched, that can be arranged too.)

First take a look at the input file I created to test special situations:

```
$cat ff

13960   12602   gene
13963   12602   rRNA
10030   24022   general
10040   32002   rRNA
30902   32098   gene
34003   30934   gene
40902   30921   rRNA
42093   40023   zymogene
34020           rRNA
30202   10030   para
40302   20030   gene
               crRNA
```

Here `gene` will be replaced with `rRNA` on exactly two lines: those that begin with the numbers 13960 and 34003. Note the line that begins with 42093 - `gene` appears at the end, but not as a complete word, and it should not be replaced. Also the last line ends with the string `rRNA`, but since that is a word fragment, not a complete word, the `gene` above it should not be replaced.

Then:

```
$ sed '{N;s/\bgene\(\n.*\brRNA\)$/rRNA\1/;P;D}' ff

13963   12602   rRNA
13963   12602   rRNA
10030   24022   general
10040   32002   rRNA
30902   32098   gene
34003   30934   rRNA
40902   30921   rRNA
42093   40023   zymogene
34020           rRNA
30202   10030   para
40302   20030   gene
               crRNA
```

Processing starts with the first line. At each step: `N` adds a newline and the next line of input to the pattern space; `s` replaces `gene` with `rRNA` if the first line ends with the full word `gene` and the second ends with the full word `rRNA` (note the use of the `\b` assertion); `P` prints the first line from the pattern space (whether it was left unchanged or it underwent the `gene` <- `rRNA` substitution); `D` then deletes that first line (including the newline) from the pattern space. Then the cycle starts again: `N` adds a newline and the next input line to the pattern space, etc. When we reach the last line, N does nothing (as there are no more lines in the file); the `s` command will automatically find no match, `P` will print the last line, `D` will delete it and we are done. Note that in the POSIX standard, on the last line, if `N` finds no "next" line, `sed` terminates (and therefore the last line is not `P`rinted); so this solution takes full advantage of this **GNU** extension of the `N` command.